# Adding and removing cells from table via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen a fair amount about add/remove table rows but not much about adding/removing table cells.  I am using a table to make a grid of squares, then merging groups of squares into rectangles (making Tetris-like shapes).  I delete several squares when creating a rectangle, set the colspan of its "index cell" to fill in the gap left by deleted cells.  Later I need to reverse this -- index cell back to square, then replacing the "missing"  elements with programatically-generated new ones.

The problem is if I later need to remove any of these generated cells for the next shape, the program can't find them.  I can see them on the DOM and even check their classes/ids, but to the program they are invisible (can't select via jQuery id or class selector).  Hint: cellindex for these cells is -1 -- as if the table thinks they are appended somewhere else in the DOM hierarchy.

Here's HTML:

```
                <td class="cell"></td>
                <td class="cell"></td>
                <td class="cell enterBtn" colspan="3" rowspan="1" id="enterBtn"></td>
                <td class="cell"></td>
                <td class="cell"></td>
```

Here's JavaScript trying to create the "fill in" cells after returning a rectangle to square shape:

```
// ======= ======= ======= unMergeArea ======= ======= =======
Game.prototype.unMergeArea = function(whichArea) {
    var indexCell = this.tableCellsArray[whichArea.iR][whichArea.iC];
    $(indexCell).attr("colSpan", 1);
    $(indexCell).attr("rowSpan", 1);
    for (var j = 0; j < whichArea.iH; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < whichArea.iW; i++) {
            if (!((i == 0) && (j == 0))) {
                var newCell = document.createElement("td");
                $(indexCell).after(newCell);
                $(newCell).addClass("cell");
            }
        }
    }
    $(indexCell).removeClass(whichArea.class);
    $(indexCell).addClass("cell");
    return indexCell;
}
```

And here's script for later remove cells for another rectangle to fill in. The program can not find "nextCell":

```
// ======= ======= ======= mergeArea ======= ======= =======
Game.prototype.mergeArea = function(whichArea) {
    var nextCell;
    var indexCell = this.tableCellsArray[whichArea.iR][whichArea.iC];
    for (var j = 0; j < whichArea.iH; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < whichArea.iW; i++) {
            if (!((i == 0) && (j == 0))) {
                nextCell = $(this.tableCellsArray[whichArea.iR + j][whichArea.iC + i]);
                $(nextCell).remove();
                $(nextCell).addClass("gone");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $(indexCell).attr("colSpan", whichArea.iW);
    $(indexCell).attr("rowSpan", whichArea.iH);
    $(indexCell).addClass(whichArea.class);
    return indexCell;
}
```

Any thoughts?  This has been agonizing!

Comment: you should use `tableRow.insertCell` rather than `document.createElement("td")`, `tableRow` being a reference to a table row...

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox. Easier to help seeing how these are called and what `whichArea` is

Comment: Also suspect that the problem lies in a cached version of the cells in table ...`this.tableCellsArray` . Once you remove from DOM,  object reference stored in array no longer exists